# array manipulation: calculate odds ratios for a layer in a 3-way table

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

This is a question about array and data frame manipulation and calculation, in the
context of models for log odds in contingency tables. The closest question I've found to this is [How can i calculate odds ratio in many table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484563/how-can-i-calculate-odds-ratio-in-many-table), but mine is more general.

I have a data frame representing a 3-way frequency table, of size 5 (litter) x 2 (treatment) x 3 (deaths).
"Freq" is the frequency in each cell, and deaths is the response variable.

```
Mice <-
structure(list(litter = c(7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L), treatment = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), deaths = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", 
"2+"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(58L, 75L, 49L, 58L, 33L, 45L, 
15L, 39L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 19L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 22L, 13L, 22L, 12L, 
15L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 15L, 10L, 15L, 18L, 17L, 8L)), .Names = c("litter", 
"treatment", "deaths", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

From this, I want to calculate the log odds for adjacent categories of the last variable (deaths)
and have this value in a data frame with factors litter (5), treatment (2), and contrast (2), as detailed below.

The data can be seen in xtabs() form:

```
mice.tab <- xtabs(Freq ~ litter + treatment + deaths, data=Mice)
ftable(mice.tab)

                 deaths  0  1 2+
litter treatment                
7      A                58 11  5
       B                75 19  7
8      A                49 14 10
       B                58 17  8
9      A                33 18 15
       B                45 22 10
10     A                15 13 15
       B                39 22 18
11     A                 4 12 17
       B                 5 15  8
>
```

From this, I want to calculate the (adjacent) log odds of 0 vs. 1 and 1 vs.2+ deaths, which is easy in
array format,

```
odds1 <- log(mice.tab[,,1]/mice.tab[,,2])  # contrast 0:1
odds2 <- log(mice.tab[,,2]/mice.tab[,,3])  # contrast 1:2+

odds1
      treatment
litter          A          B
    7   1.6625477  1.3730491
    8   1.2527630  1.2272297
    9   0.6061358  0.7156200
    10  0.1431008  0.5725192
    11 -1.0986123 -1.0986123
>
```

But, for analysis, I want to have these in a data frame, with factors litter, treatment and contrast
and a column, 'logodds' containing the entries in the odds1 and odds2 tables, suitably strung out.

More generally, for an I x J x K table, where the last factor is the response, my desired result
is a data frame of IJ(K-1) rows, with adjacent log odds in a 'logodds' column, and ideally, I'd like
to have a general function to do this.

Note that if T is the 10 x 3 matrix of frequencies shown by ftable(), the calculation is essentially

```
log(T) %*% matrix(c(1, -1, 0,
                    0,  1, -1))
```

followed by reshaping and labeling.

Can anyone help with this?